# How to fix list.index(min(list)) when min(list) is in scientific notation

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, data-science

Pretty self explanatory, my list has a smallest value of 3.4972054734350166e-06. I want to find where in the list this is using

```py
list.index(min(list))
```

but it gives an error of:

```py
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)

<ipython-input-75-218f090090e9> in <module>()
     15 print(sum(list) / len(list))
     16 print("The highest r2 value is:",max(list),"from ",country_data[list.index(max(list))].name[0])
---> 17 print(country_data[list.index(min(list))].name[0])

1 frames

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py in get_value(self, series, key)
   4373         try:
   4374             return self._engine.get_value(s, k,
-> 4375                                           tz=getattr(series.dtype, 'tz', None))
   4376         except KeyError as e1:
   4377             if len(self) > 0 and (self.holds_integer() or self.is_boolean()):

pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_value()

pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_value()

pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.Int64HashTable.get_item()

pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.Int64HashTable.get_item()

KeyError: 0
```

The code works with index(max(list)).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this way list_name.index(min(list_name)) ;)

Comment: I'm sorry there was a typo in the body of my question, it was right in the title. Fixed it. But now that you say that, I tried to print that value and it works, just doesn't work when I try to manipulate that number as a variable.

Comment: I think it solved it, for some reason when I did:

```python
print("The highest r2 value is:",max(list),"from ",country_data[list.index(max(list))].name[0])
```
I was given an error because of a split I made earlier in the code.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using `numpy` according to your tag, simply use `argmin` letting `axis=None`

> **numpy.argmin**
>
> Returns the indices of the minimum values along an axis.

```
np.argmin(arr)
```